# Am i using the Tomcat webserver or not?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

so i'm making this application in Spring Boot and i know by default, spring boot is embedded to tomcat web server. But i'm not sure whether it's tomcat web server or else because in my dependency there is no tomcat dependency in my code. but i access the webserver succesfully through

```
localhost:8080
```

and here is my dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
 </dependency>
```

so am i using the tomcat server or not?

Comment: Yes, you are using tomcat. It's embedded by default

Comment: You are. `starter` artifacts usually include many more dependencies within them so even though you only put 1 dependency in your pom file you are actually adding many.

Answer (score 1):

You're using embedded tomcat by default as spring-boot-starter-web has a dependency on tomcat libraries which are transitive.

To be more precise, spring-boot-starter-web among other things has the following definition in its pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your logs, please, or console messages,

Spring Boot prints this

```
2018-09-25 00:45:24 INFO   TomcatWebServer 91: Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
```

Answer (score 0):

spring-boot-starter-web comes with Embedded Tomcat. In case you want to edit the

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
</dependency>

It has the below properties :
server:
port:
undertow:
ioThreads:
workerThreads:
accesslog:
enabled:
compression:
enabled:
mimeTypes:
minResponseSize:
```